# ¿Cómo podría almacenar los resultados de un bucle en myslq?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

quería saber como poder pasar los resultados de un **bucle** a una base de datos **mysql**, concretamente en `phpmyadmin`. Aquí les dejo mi código `PHP` (estoy escaneado una red y mi objetivo es almacenar por separado tanto las IPs que han dado un *ping* positivo como las que no)

```
<?php
     for($m=1; $m<255; $m++){
         $res = shell_exec("ping -n 2 -w 1 10.138.53.$m");

         if (strpos($res, "recibidos = 0")) {
             echo "No se ha podido establecer conexión con la IP 10.138.53.$m";
             echo "<br>";

         }else{
             echo "El ping a la IP 10.138.53.$m ha sido exitosa";
             echo "<br>";      
         }
    }
?>
```

Aquí la estructura que tengo en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: php tiene sus propias funciones para conectar a bbdd mysql. Echa un vistazo en el buscador de stackoverflow, que hay muchos ejemplos de como insertar en bbdd, ok?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero Crear un archivo `conexion.php` en la misma carpeta done tienes el documento

escribe el siguiente codigo

```html
<?php 

//En caso de tener una diferente base de datos
//Cambia la ubicacion del servidor en el __constructor

class conexion {

 private $server;
 private $user;
 private $pswd;
 private $database;
 private $port;
 private $conexion;



 public function __construct(){
     $this->server = "localhost"; //la direccion de tu servidor
     $this->user = "root"; //usuario de tu base de datos
     $this->pwsd = ""; //contraseña
     $this->database ="base"; //nombre de tu base de dato
     $this->port ="3306"; //puerto

     $this->conexion =  new mysqli($this->server,$this->user,$this->pwsd,$this->database,$this->port);
     if( $this->conexion -> connect_errno){
         die($this->conexion -> connect_error);
     }
 }

 //guardar , modificar , eliminar 
 function NonQuery($sqlstr){
     $result = $this->conexion->query($sqlstr);
     return $this->conexion -> affected_rows;
 }

 //select
function ObtenerRegistros($sqlstr){
    $result = $this->conexion->query($sqlstr);
    $resultArray  = array();
    foreach( $result  as $registros ){
        $resultArray[] = $registros;
    }
    return $this->ConvertirUTF8($resultArray);
 }

 //utf-8
function ConvertirUTF8($array){
    array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$item,$key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item,'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode( $item);
        }
    });
    return  $array;
}


    
}

?>
```

luego en la pagina donde tienes el bucle

```html
<?php
    require_once('conexion.php');
    $db = new conexion;

    for($m=1; $m<255; $m++){
        $res = shell_exec("ping -n 2 -w 1 10.138.53.$m");

        if (strpos($res, "recibidos = 0")) {
            echo "No se ha podido establecer conexión con la IP 10.138.53.$m";
            echo "<br>";
        }else{
  
            $query = "insert into tabla (id,ip)values('el id','la ip')";
            $respuesta = $db->NonQuery($query);
            if($respuesta){
                echo "se guardo";
            }else{
                echo no se guardo";
            }
            echo "El ping a la IP 10.138.53.$m ha sido exitosa";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Buenas compañero, probando tu código con mis propias ideas, más otras cosas que necesitaba, al final conseguí lograrlo. Perdón por responder tan tarde.

Comment: Que bueno que haya resulto tu problema. Un saludo y feliz de haberte ayudado un poco

Answer (score 1):

Aquí dejo el código que al final me sirvió.

```
<?php
$hora= date ("h:i:s");
$fecha= date ("Y-m-d");
$fecha_actual= "$fecha $hora";

for($n=50; $n<100; $n++){
    for($m=1; $m<255; $m++){
        //$res = shell_exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 10.138.53.$m");
        $res = shell_exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 10.138.$n.$m");

        $ip = "10.138.$n.$m";

        $servername = '127.0.0.1';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $dbname = 'ping';

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $conn->set_charset("utf8"); //establecer codificación utf8
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error);
        }            

        if (strpos($res, "recibidos = 0")) {

            $sql = "insert into pings (ip, fecha, ping_b, ping_m) values (INET_ATON('$ip'), '$fecha_actual', 0, 1)";
            $resultado= $conn->query($sql);         

        }else{

            $sql = "insert into pings (ip, fecha, ping_b, ping_m) values (INET_ATON('$ip'), '$fecha_actual', 1, 0)";
            $resultado= $conn->query($sql);         

        }

    }
}?>
```

Mi objetivo era guardar el resultado de un ping, tanto negativo como positivo, la IP a la que se le hizo dicho ping, y la fecha y la hora del barrido de IP´s comprobadas.
Espero que pueda servir de ayuda a futuros compañeros :)